# Did I ruin my griddle by overheating it?

Tags: appliances, oven, metal

So turns out the thermostat control on our griddle was broken. We ran it on full blast for about thirty minutes. Started to notice the adhesive bubbling on the sides then turned it off to investigate.

It's a much darker color than it was before, and seeing the adhesive worries me. Is this griddle still 100% safe to use or should we buy a new one?

[image: full]
[image: up close front]
[image: top]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this one needs to be thrown out, or more fully disabled so someone else does not pick it out of the trash to use it and then thrown out.

The bubbly plastic bits in where the food goes are not a good thing, and there may well be some hidden damage as well.

If it was me, I would not replace it with the exact same model, either. I would expect the sides to be welded in place, or stamped into a solid sheet; not glued like that.